# Attaching an element (height:auto) at the bottom of its parent, without position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I wish to create a kind of podium, with 3 columns inside (with 1col.height < 2ndcol.height < 3dcol.height).
Since it's a podium,both columns have to be attached at the bottom of the container which stocks them.
And here is my big problem : columns have to got height:auto. And the parent container too.

And, if I use the famous position:absolute for my columns, I can't rely on having my parent container with a successful height:auto (-> columns won't be anymore in the flow :(  ).

Consequently, I'm trapped (because I want to avoid Javascript).
If you have any idea to help me creating my podium display, I'm very interested in knowing it :)

PS: I tried clearfix tips but they don't work with absolute elements. And the other solutions I found while searching don't fix my problem : /

Thank you !

Comment: Little code will be better.....

Answer (score 2):

If you use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;` on the columns they will be aligned next to each other and growing from the bottom.

[Se Fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/huwtL/)

Comment: Ouch, I saw this solution in other topics but I thought that only concerned texts.Well, sorry for my topic and thank you very much for your answer : that's perfect !